# disable lightbox for mobile

Tags: jquery, css, html, lightbox

I have managed to conditionally load the css and js for the lightbox depending on the window width. However when the link is clicked it still opens the larger image in a new window.

I would like to just show the thumbnail img without the option of clicking it to view it as a larger image in a new window when the window width is below 479px.

Is this at all possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<li class="gallery-item-container ">
    <a data-original="l-img1.jpg" href="l-img1.jpg" class="zoombox effect-justopacity lazy"><img class="thumb-gamma lazy" data-original="img1.jpg" src="img1.jpg" alt="professional photography services cyprus" height="270" width="270"/></a>         
</li>
```

edit: maybe appending the href attribute to the a tag, is there a way to do that for each image?

Comment: I don't quite understand, if you don't want it to open the image in a new tab, just remove the anchor from around the image. If you mean on mobile only, you could detect a mobile user agent in the JS that's binded to that anchor to open the lightbox, then return false if it's a mobile.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Do you have a code example as my jquery knowledge isn't the best.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily hide the button on :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) { .zoombox {display: none;} }
```